# Shutdown Procedure

Tags: raspbian

Folks,

If I shut down my Pi using "sudo shutdown -h now": -

1. does Raspbian *cleanly* stop MySQL database that is running on the Pi?
2. does Raspbian *cleanly* stop Tomcat server that is running on the Pi?
3. does Raspbian *cleanly* umount my portable external USB HDD?
4. what happens to above 3 scenarios if I **reboot** using "sudo shutdown **-r** now"?

Currently, I have written scripts that will stop (not kill) MySQL, Tomcat, umount the HDD and finally kick off the "sudo shutdown" sequence. Am I being too paranoid by not using "sudo shutdown" directly?

Thanks.

Comment: No need to worry. Just as a side note; you can just `sudo halt` and `sudo reboot`. The are equivalent to your commands, but a lot shorter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

linux has several runlevels, basically shutdown command changes runlevel to 6, resulting in running all scripts from `/etc/rc6.d`, that unmount file system and stop the required daemons. I can tell you that external mounts are unmounted by `K05umountnfs.sh` script, but I don't have mysql or tomcat installed, check your system if they have similar scripts (apache, httpd, exim, ntp, gpsd all do).

anyway, seems like you're being too paranoid. any reasonable software has proper scripts written if the authors think the software requires any special handling and/or shutdown procedures. you may just use `shutdown -r now` at any time.

ps. what's the reason to halt raspberry pi? save whopping 3W of electric power? you should be much more concerned about your processor and memory get detached from frequent temperature changes...

Comment: Much like Sheldon Cooper, I am trying to find a "perfect" location for the Pi in my new apartment (based on WiFi strength etc.). So I have to shut it down between moves. Also, I found /etc/rc6.d/K01mysql that seems to be doing all  the right things provided someone sends "stop" argument to it. Thanks for all the information.

Comment: @user309223 the perfect location for your Raspi would be next to your TV set, so you have a large screen to look at while typing commands. and regarding wifi -- just dont, raspi is by no means a wearable device, and deserves its own ethernet cable that works much faster and does not drop connection from time to time.