# How to safely shutdown raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, shutdown

I have a [iono-pi](https://www.sferalabs.cc/iono-pi/) which sits on top of the raspberry pi. I have connected this to a machine so the pi is getting power from the machine. When the machine starts for production, pi also starts and when the machine is powered down after the shift, pi also shutdown but this shutdown process is not a normal shutdown process as there is no `shutdown` command involved in it.

Is there any way we can safely power down the pi in this scenario.?

Comment: It is simple to shutdown Raspberry Pi OS with a command or contact closure. You wouldn't turn off a lathe without a proper procedure.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to look at this:

**Try operating systems that reside only in RAM once booted.**

Some version of Linux (e.g. [Tiny Core](http://www.tinycorelinux.net/)) will boot from SD Card and then run solely in RAM stopping any corruption on the Pi SD card file system.

**Try super capacitors**

Super capacitors can provide a very short term power supply and be charged from the normal Pi supply.  You would then add a power sensor to the incoming supply and trigger the Pi to shut down when that drops.

**Try a UPS hat**

Many small UPS hats are available and these come with support programs to switch the Pi off and back on again when suppliers change

I not mention the obvious ones (except in the foot note) of staff turning the Pi off first (not 100%), running the Pi from a separate supply (may not be possible) or shooting the engineer who designed using the Pi and just killing the power without considering the OS - it's not a microcontroller...

Comment: `shooting the engineer who designed using the Pi and just killing the power without considering the OS` No engineers designed it to make it properly shutdown but this is actually the scenario where its not possible to shutdown the device. Anyways I will consider some of the options you mentioned.

Comment: @SAndrew In fact the Pi is no different to any other computer. Killing the power on any system risks corruption so the only engineer who should be shot is the one who "designed" your machine.

Comment: Looks like I will have to kill myself. But this is just for the POC level and I am definelty going to change the whole procedure. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do as said by others, have a supercapacitor to give you seconds of power after mains removal. Then you would need an analog-to-digital converter (I have used ADS1115 https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-4-channel-adc-breakouts/python-circuitpython ) to read the supercapacitor voltage.

Then keep a python program (for example) running to shutdown [Shutdown Procedure](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15508/shutdown-procedure) the Pi as the voltage decreases.

I have made that and it works nicely. Also there is the option of using a UPS with batteries to give you that extra time you need, but that would be overkill for what you need.